# How to allow editing only numbers after dot in input tag?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hook-form

Currently I have an input tag and there I only allow numbers like 0.1, 0.123, 0.2,.... (numbers like that).
I use react-hook-form for this input tag.
`

```
 <input
      type="text"
      {...register("version")}
      onChange={(e: any) => {
       setValue("version", e.target.value)
      }}
      className={`form-control project-form-control rounded-0 input-digga2 ${
       errors.version ? "is-invalid" : ""
       }`}
      name="version"
      pattern="[0-9.]"
      />
```

`

And what I want to do when I do onChange is there a way I can only allow the user to change the numbers after the dot and it will still remain "0.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp, as I show you below.

```
if (value.match(/\w\../) && !value.match(/[A-Za-z]\.\d/)) {
      return;
}
```

I created a sandbox code and it works, check it out:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-response-or8pzh

I also reorder your code to improve the good reading of your code. Let me suggest to you something when you're working with react.

- Avoid putting functions and validations in your render-HTML-syntax code, this is one of the reasons why a lot of developers have problems understanding the code.

Comment: First of all, i wanna say thank you so much @jircdeveloper!
Really thank you for your kindness to me.
I have tested your code, but it seems to be quite different from my requirements. My aim is to be in the input tag where the user can still enter the numbers 0.1, 0.2, 0.12,.... or similar and if the user wants to change it, only the numbers after the dot it are allowed to change. And the default input field will be "0." and it is not allowed to change "0." which is changed only after the dot.
Can you help me make some adjustments?

Comment: Did you change your description? I didn't understand the first time, well, in fact, the solution is very similar, you only need to change the regexp. I already made the change on the sandbox page. Check it out.  and let me know if is ok for you.

Comment: I have solved this problem, thank you so much @jircdeveloper!